# SQL SERVER - OBJECT_ID AND type (N) purpose

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a question regarding OBJECT_ID and using it with `DROP` and `CREATE` tables.

```
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
```

What does the "N" in the above code do? I understand that 'U' is a user-defined table.  I tried looking the meaning of 'N' however I cannot find a sastifying reason.

**Two examples:**

Does the 'N' do anything specific when checking the existance of a user-defined table for the purpose of dropping or creating a table?

Comment: National character literal. (Unicode.)

Comment: What function does it have? Would it absence affect the operation with the argument 'U' (User-defined)?

Comment: It's just an indication that the following literal may contain Unicode characters. N'U' is equal to 'U' value wise, but different data types.